# Convert empty object to string

Tags: knockout.js, object-to-string

I have a problem that when I save my form with an empty field, it is saved but when I open the form to edit it, it shows `[object object]` instead of empty value in that field. I am looking the way to loop over the properties of an object in `knockout.js` while saing the form.

### Edit

The form binding is here

```
ko.bindingHandlers.renderForm = {

    init : function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel,
            bindingContext) {
        if (!viewModel.formData) {
            viewModel.formData = false;
        }
        if (! isNullOrEmpty(viewModel.formData)) {
            console.log("hello");
            $.each(viewModel.formData, function(key, val){
                if ($.isEmptyObject(val)) {
                    viewModel.formData[key] = '';
                }
            });
        }
        console.log(viewModel.formData['remarks']);
        //viewModel.formData.data = some functionto convertempty object to empty string(viewModel.formData.data);
        renderForm(viewModel.formXml, element, viewModel.formData, viewModel.formOptions);

    }

};
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle that shows the problem ?

Comment: Well how I will put xml in fiddle?

Comment: By Xml do you mean the ajax response ? If yes, you can may be simulate the server response by a timeout.
But if it's hard to make a fiddle, just post the part of code which doesn't work. Because it's impossible to say where the "[object object]" comes from without code.

Comment: I think it will be very hard to find what is not working wintout a fiddle. You sould post at least the view and the view model.

Comment: ah well I have done it. I will post view model also

Comment: why are you looking for this on render form and not on submit?  if the user submits null you should be passing that to the service appropriately.  then render would only be needed if you wanted something magic to happen...which you wouldn't...default value would be light gray and still make more sense...